# Does True use more memory than False?

Tags: java, memory, binary, boolean

If I had some condition which checks whether it is true, then do this. Would it be different from if it checks whether it is not false and the other way around ? Would it also take less space if checking was in boolean rather than very low digit ?
In Java, but maybe other languages too.

```
boolean x;
byte y,k,z,a;
//x and k tests, y, z and a just assigned value if they pass any of these tests
if(x==true){y=0;}  if(x!=true){z=1}  //Are these quicker or take less space
if(x!=false){y=0;} if(x==false){z=1} //Than these ?

if(k==1){a=2;} //Or these ?
if(k!=1){a=2;}
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure the answer is "no" no matter which language you're talking about that has a decent compiler/runtime, however it would help to narrow it down to a single language.

Comment: "if(x==true)" can be shortened to just "if(x)" and "if(x!=true)" to "if(!x)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At runtime, the space taken up by a variable of primitive type (such as boolean) does not depend on its value.

Therefore, at most you will see a slight increase (a few bytes) in the size of the class file, or the source code. Since the class and source file are only stored once, such a difference would be totally negligible.

As for execution speed, it is likely the compiler will optimize that, and even if it doesn't the just-in-time compiler will. And even if that weren't the case, negating a boolean takes about 1 ns (0.000000001 seconds), so its very unlikely to measurably impact the speed of your program.